# Qt Script constructor function

Tags: qt, constructor

I am reading through the Qt scripting documentation and came across this passage.

> Note that, even though it is not considered good practice, there is
>   nothing that stops you from choosing to ignore the default constructed
>   (this) object when your function is called as a constructor and
>   creating your own object anyway; simply have the constructor return
>   that object. The object will "override" the default object that the
>   engine constructed

I am confused as to what this means. What it means by 'this'  object and the constructor object. Does this mean it is favored to have a this object rather than having a constructor?

Could some please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the example from the Qt documentation:

```
function Book(isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

The constructor `Book()` adds an `isbn` property to the `this` object, which is returned automatically (i.e. without an explicit `return` statement). However, you are free to return your own object from a constructor, e.g. you could do

```
function Book(isbn) {
    return {isbn : isbn};
}
```

In the latter case, you ignore the `this` object, create a new object and return it instead.